# Sequence of operations

Tags: java, swing, timer

Trying to understand the rules for using swing classes.
The question arose:
suppose at the beginning of the program I create a swing Timer object and run it

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000,this);
myTimer.start();
```

The program continues, some calculations, calculations, etc. are performed.
But it takes 1000ms and myTimer calls the actionPerformed () method.
I want to understand in what sequence the operations will be performed.
Maybe the main program will stop and wait until the execution of the actionPerformed () method has finished?
Or maybe another option?
Who in the know tell me how the operations will actually be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActionPerformed` method will be invoked on the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT).
That thread will run concurrently with the main thread and other threads unless those threads are programmed to alter their behavior.  All events are processed on the EDT.  Among others that includes listeners and painting requests.  As those events are processed sequentially, it is important to keep the time spent in the EDT to a minimum.  Otherwise, other events will not be processed in a timely fashion.

You can read more about [Currency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in the java tutorials.